# How to do CSS Sprites with in an unordered list

Tags: css-sprites

I'm having some issues with CSS sprites.

I'm a CSS novice and this is what I've come up with.

http://jsfiddle.net/mumgkef7/

It needs to be inside a unordered list.

Part of the CSS, whole CSS can be found on jsfiddle.

```
.sprite {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://overnightsupplements.com/skin/frontend/default/galayomarket/images/media/slideshow/sprite.png);
}
.sprite.5-hour-energy {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -524.0px -64.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.BetancourtNutrition_LOGOS-BLKsw {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 47.0px;
    background-position: -2.0px -128.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 47.0px;
}
.sprite.Biotest2 {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
    background-position: -298.0px -40.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 25.0px;
}
.sprite.Cellucor {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -150.0px -167.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.Celsius {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -224.0px -2.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.HFTSLogo {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
    background-position: -150.0px -205.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 25.0px;
}
.sprite.HPFLogo-s {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 37.0px;
    background-position: -150.0px -128.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 37.0px;
}
.sprite.Modjo-Hydrate-Elite {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -224.0px -114.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.MusclePharm-s {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 72.0px;
    background-position: -2.0px -2.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 72.0px;
}
.sprite.Natures_Remedies_logo {
    width: 150.0px;
    height: 50.0px;
    background-position: -2.0px -76.0px;
    background-size: 150.0px 50.0px;
}
.sprite.PharmaFreak_Logo-1 _black_lg-sJPG {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 14.0px;
    background-position: -668.0px -214.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 14.0px;
}
.sprite.Premier-s {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
    background-position: -372.0px -40.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 25.0px;
}
.sprite.PrimaforceLOGO {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 39.0px;
    background-position: -76.0px -128.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 39.0px;
}
.sprite.Proline {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
    background-position: -224.0px -40.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 25.0px;
}
.sprite.StarChem-Labs {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -228.0px -67.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.Train Naked Labs logo-s {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 22.0px;
    background-position: -76.0px -52.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 22.0px;
}
.sprite.Train Naked Labs logo {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 22.0px;
    background-position: -150.0px -52.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 22.0px;
}
.sprite.UVE {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -594.0px -2.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<ul class="sprite">
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite.5-hour-energy"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite.BetancourtNutrition_LOGOS-BLKsw"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite.Biotest2"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite.Cellucor"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading it right or if it's been typed right, but in the html you provided, you've defined the first SPAN element's class as "sprite 5-hour energy", but the class is called "sprite.5-hour-energy" (with a '.' instead of a space) in your CSS. Your problem might be a simple typo.If this isn't it, providing more details about what's unexpectedly happening or not happening will likely get you better help.

Comment: No change on the http://jsfiddle.net/mumgkef7/ site when I put the period there.  I will update the code on here.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly inside the Unordered list from the link you suggested.

Sprite Images are those images which Contains "all the images needed in your website"  in a Single Image.

Now, In order to display a particular image from the Sprite Image, You must Adjust the Backround Positions of that Span or div by referring ti the Seperate class given to each of them.

All you need to do is to link the  CSS file and and give the right path where the Image is Stored.

Comment: I've tried to do that, not sure what's wrong with my jsfiddle code.  I'm a novice at sprites.

Comment: Have you done the linking of CSS  with your HTML page roperly.?
Can you put up the whole code of your html page and css pae.?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mumgkef7/ has all the code.  I removed the code from my site until I figure out the fiddle since it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newcss1.css"  />
    </head>
    <body>
     <ul class="sprite">
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite 5-hour-energy"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite BetancourtNutrition_LOGOS-BLKsw"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite Biotest2"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider">
        <span class="sprite Cellucor"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="itemslider"><span class="sprite Celsius"></span>

    </li>
     </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now create a css file:
newcss1.css

```
.sprite {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://overnightsupplements.com/skin/frontend/default/galayomarket/images/media/slideshow/sprite.png);
}
/*.sprite  {
    width: 72px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -524.0px -64.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}*/
.sprite.BetancourtNutrition_LOGOS-BLKsw {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 47.0px;
    background-position: -2.0px -128.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 47.0px;
}
.sprite.Biotest2 {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 25.0px;
    background-position: -298.0px -40.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 25.0px;
}
.sprite.Cellucor {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -150.0px -167.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
.sprite.Celsius {
    width: 72.0px;
    height: 36.0px;
    background-position: -224.0px -2.0px;
    background-size: 72.0px 36.0px;
}
```

Just Copy Paste It. IT works Perfectly. Upvote If it works

Comment: not working for me...?  It's the same as my original code as far as I can tell.  Shows a few images, but not the correct ones, and I know the sprite coordinates are correct. It was created using Zwoptex.

Comment: Please Adjust the Coordinates then according to what you want to display. Or Just Elaborate more . I am not getting what you want exactly.